# How to stop images animation?

Tags: android, animation, gallery

The following program displays full screen images that animate automatically by using the loadAnimation() method. Here is is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public int currentimageindex=0;
Timer timer;
TimerTask task;
ImageView slidingimage;

private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
        R.drawable.picture1, R.drawable.picture2, R.drawable.picture3,
        R.drawable.picture4
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();

        }
    };

    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 3000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

        }

    }, delay, period);



}



/**
 * Helper method to start the animation on the splash screen
 */
private void AnimateandSlideShow() {


    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

    currentimageindex++;

    Animation leftToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right);


    slidingimage.startAnimation(leftToRight);




}


}
```

As you can see the full sized picture change every 4 seconds. Now what i want to do is to stop the animation after the appearance of the last image(picture 4 in this case). After fixing this,I will try fetch images from a server using JSON.

Thank you,
Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)You have to load animation until only you have image in IMAGE_IDS array

2)Then stop your timer also

Add following lines in **AnimateandSlideShow()** below **currentimageindex++**

```
if(currentimageindex <= IMAGE_IDS.length)
        {
            Animation leftToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.letf_anim);
            slidingimage.startAnimation(leftToRight);
        }
        else
        {
            timer.cancel();
        }
```

Also replace following line

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

To

```
timer = new Timer();
```

Comment: Yes. That did the job. Many thanks. I marked your answer as the corrent one:)